# Fix a div to the viewport height

Tags: html, css

My website is divided into three `div`'s left, middle and right. I want to set the height of the left one to the height of the screen using viewport `height` property.

My code is

```
#left
{
  height:1vph;
}
```

But this is not working. Please help me in doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `vph` height unit, I think you are looking for the `vh` unit. See the valid [CSS length values on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length).

Try using the value `100vh`, a value of `1` will only be 1/100th of the screen.

```
#left
{
  height:100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the viewport height (vh) of  a selected div or tag ..
Let us we want to set the `body` element as a viewport height.Then You have to use

```
body{
height: 100 vh;
}
```

Hope, It works. Thanks